# Correct meta of Writing Meta Tags

Tags: post-meta, headers

How to write this Head section thing correctly in Wordpress.

```
<meta name="author" content="The Zebra Team">
<meta name="description" content="The Zebra Team">
```

I was doing it like this  -

```
<meta name="author" content="<?php the_author(); ?>" >
<meta name="description" content="<?php the_content(); ?>" >
```

But then it was not showing me anything in the head section. I think I am doing it correctly then what is the issue?

Comment: Read this [Meta Tags in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress) or [Adding meta tags without plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160287/adding-meta-tag-without-plugin)

Comment: So you want to say that Wordpres sis unable to read this →
<meta name="author" content="<?php the_author(); ?>" >
<meta name="description" content="<?php the_content(); ?>" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to check if the loaded page is a post, and use the [Wordpress loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) to get the right data.

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
   while ( have_posts() ) {
      the_post(); ?>
      <meta name="author" content="<?php the_author(); ?>" >
      <meta name="description" content="<?php the_content(); ?>" >
   <?php
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe that this should work. I have a question what is the better way to do this. Leave it empty I mean completely remove this part →
<meta name="author" content="The Zebra Team">
<meta name="description" content="The Zebra Team">
and then plugins like Yoast Seo Plugin do the needfull. Is that a better way?

Comment: In the meanwhile, I was searching many other blogs and find that some people suggesting to do it like this →
<meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />

Which one is a better option or a better practice to write things in Wordpress?

Comment: @Champion I highly recommend to leave the tags out of your header and let Yoast SEO plugin do the rest.

Comment: @Champion `the_content()` returns the content of a post. `bloginfo('description')` returns the "slogan" (added under settings -> general) of your website. These two are total different things.