# How to add meta tags on password-protected homepage?

Tags: tags, password

I am currently using a plugin called Very Simple Password which requires viewers to input a password to access the site. I currently have Yoast installed to fix my meta tags, however whenever I post the link on my social media (especially Facebook), the meta tags I've set there are not reflecting. Instead, it's reflecting the properties from the password-protected homepage generated by Very Simple Password. I've scraped using the Facebook debugger tool, but even the Open Graph properties did not reflect.

Is there a way for me to add meta tags to the password-protected homepage? I've checked the plugin's php files and when I've added the [meta tags manually](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160287/adding-meta-tag-without-plugin?newreg=9db0f78437304b298368bfd0496cdb90), I keep getting an error.

Comment: You're worrying about SEO meta tags on a password-protected page? That doesn't quite compute for me.

Comment: I'm fixing the SEO meta tags so that the link previews will appear correctly on social media.

Comment: Don't know for sure, but I'm guessing that the same code that keeps users-without-passwords from accessing page content prevents social media from scraping - which makes sense functionality-wise. What does the page source look like when fetched or accessed by someone without a password - does it show the tags? You also might try storing default image tags in an protected folder or different stie. Wondering if you need to instead password protect sections of your page (e.g., entry content) rather than the site.

Answer (score 1):

So from the point of view of your website Facebook is just like any other visitor. Either the content is hidden for everyone or it isn't for everyone.

Even if you'd try to detect Facebook and show them something different this punches a huge hole into your password-protection and makes it pretty much pointless as it is quite trivial for any random visitor to appear as if they where Facebook.